# I have published a power bi report while the filter is working correctly but it's not fetching the data correctly what can I do to resolve this?

Tags: powerbi, report

I have published a power bi report while the filter is working correctly but it's not fetching the data correctly what can I do to resolve this?

what can I do to make sure the filter will fetch the data correctly

try republishing the report didn't work

Comment: Seems like a data quality issue/